# IBM Tealeaf and Worklight 6.1.0.01-2 Android App

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to integrate Tealeaf in a Worklight-based Android app.

First step I took was to follow the Tealeaf support team's steps to integrating and with the files they provided (uicandroid.jar). They were not entirely familiar with the Worklight so they walked me through the Native App way. However this worked just fine and I was able to return the expected results to Logcat when running the app on device. The only issue with this is every time I do a new Android build, I have to follow these steps again.

I am suspecting its just an issue with the build path, but I have added to the build path the jar file. I have tried many different directories including (apps/libs, apps/lib, apps/android/native/libs, apps/android/libs) and the file never carries over after android build leaving 'red lines' in my native/src//.java file as I have added....

```
import com.tl.uic.Tealeaf;      // this is redlined 'com.tl'
```

... and changed function to:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    Tealeaf tealeaf = new Tealeaf(getApplication());     // this is redlined 'Tealeaf' on both
    Tealeaf.enable();                                    // this is redlined 'Tealeaf'
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
}
```

The red lines go away after manually adding native/libs/uicandroid.jar after the build.

Other things I have tried. disregarding the download of the SDK and adding manually, I add via application-descriptor.xml the 'optional features/analytics', update the TLFConfigurableItems.properties file to point to Tealeaf server and have no filters to include (type1,2,4,5,6) then build. Tealeaf works, but it doesn't show all the data im looking for in logcat. It only shows type 1 data, no UI data which is what I really need. I have follow the IBM documentation for Worklight 5.6, 6.1 doesn't really have any useful instructions.

I have even installed WL 6.2 and added the Tealeaf Analytics and still no UI data.

any thoughts or direction would be great.

Basically the only way it works is before build, include the generated JS file, update the /.java file and after build, add the downloaded TLFConfigurableItems.properties and uicandroid.jar file. I need this to happen before the build as it goes in a branch/repo where other developers are doing different stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Things changed between worklight 6.1 and 6.2 with regard to Tealeaf and the Optional Feature.  On 6.1 the Tealeaf library and properties file will be removed during a rebuild.  On 6.2, that is not necessarily the case if you added your own versions of the files to your project.

Another difference between 6.1 and 6.2 is the default behavior specified in the TLFConfigurableItems.properties.  In 6.1 filtering is enabled, interval sending is disabled, and manual sending is enabled, which means events are only sent when Tealeaf is told to send explicitly.  In 6.2, the properties file will match a typical version 9 Tealeaf SDK properties file which means filtering is disabled, intervals sending is enabled and manual sending is disabled.

I think using Worklight 6.2 should address the building issues you were seeing (either because you can use the included version of the Tealeaf files, or because ones you add yourself aren't removed during a rebuild).  As for the missing UI events, I am not sure; perhaps someone else can comment on that.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are not seeing UI events in your log is because your JavaScript layer needs to activate Tealeaf by linking to a Tealeaf Configuration script. Additionally in Worklight 6.2, you need to hook in Tealeaf engine from the Java side by following some standard integration steps. This involves writing some Java code. In Worklight 6.1, the Java side is auto integrated via the Worklight Analytics module.

Basically, depending on which version of Worklight you want to use, (6.1 or 6.2), you need to follow a different set of Tealeaf integration steps.

Sorry to answer a question with a question, but if you can tell me which version of Worklight you are looking to use, I can guide you accordingly with hooking in Tealeaf

Comment: As posted in the topic, I am targeting the use of 6.1. However, my javascript layer has been generated via the Tealeaf wizard that was provided with the uicandroid.jar. Also to mention, this jar for android, also came with ios and a few others. The JS file is very lengthy and I am under the impression it should be supportive for different devices. Though it does make sense the JS file I have isn't generated for the Worklight module. It sounds like the best option is to use the WL module and figure out what to change to get the WL module to enable UI data.

Comment: For 6.1, you will go through the Worklight Analytics module. You will not need to write any integration code on the Java side of things as that is taken care of by the Worklight Analytics module. On the JavaScript side, there are two JS files that are involved. You need to make sure the "analytics.js" file is linked in your index.html. This includes the Tealeaf stuff needed. In addition, you need to now activate/configure Tealeaf using another JS file. I believe it should be called "defaultconfiguration.js". Do you happen to have this file in your Tealeaf distribution

Comment: make sure in your index.html, you add the "defaultconfiguration.js" script *after* the "analytics.js" script. This will include the Tealeaf engine and configure it. Once this is established, you should see Tealeaf messages in your Log when you run your App under the "UICAndroid" log tag

Comment: As I am using WL 6.1 and using a project branch that I have not done anything with Tealeaf/Analytic. I have added the analytic module in the application descriptor. However in this process the only new populated files I can see are iOS/Android specifics (UICAndroid.jar and couple for iOS) and the TLFConfigurableItems.properties(the configuration file that points to PostMessageUrl). This module doesn't appear to have provided any JS files. In experimenting/trial-error I have added my previous tealeaf.js to the mix and included in my index.html. I can confirm in log, it only see data type 1,3,6.